# Servo motor keep shaking while using software PWM to drive

Tags: pwm, pigpio, node.js, servo, javascript

Greet everyone, I am using JavaScript with [**pigpio**](https://github.com/fivdi/pigpio) to develop my learning project.

How come my servo motor keeps shaking when I drive it by program PWM? codes are posted as follow:

```
    var servo1GPIO = new Gpio(20, { mode: Gpio.OUTPUT });

    var func = () => {
        servo1GPIO.digitalWrite(1);
        setTimeout(() => {
            servo1GPIO.digitalWrite(0);
        }, 2);
    };

    setInterval(func, 20);
```

The above code demonstrate how my servo motor was drove with a 2ms duty cycle, but keep shakes...

However, if I use the function [`servoWrite(pulseWidth)`](https://github.com/fivdi/pigpio/blob/master/doc/gpio.md#servowritepulsewidth) built in by pigpio, it works perfectly. May I know what is the different between these two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the pulse is used by the servo hardware to set the angle of the servo horn.  If the length of the pulses differ then the servo will be continually shifting angle.  Typically a 10 µs difference in length of pulse will result in a 1 degree difference in angle.

With software timed pulses the accuracy is not very precise and can easily change by several microseconds from pulse to pulse resulting in visible jitter.

With hardware timed pulses this is much less likely as  the pulses are more accurately timed.

The servoWrite method uses hardware timed PWM.

Comment: Is hardware timed PWM the same with hardware PWM? Seems it is only available on certain pin only. How come `servoWrite()` can be used on every pin?

Comment: No, pigpio can provide hardware timed PWM on all GPIO.  That's what servoWrite uses.